# Delphi - How to get total disk space of Windows drive?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need to get total disk space in Delphi program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use DiskSize and DiskFree functions for this problem.
ComboBox1 contains a list of drives letters.

```
var
  Disk: Integer;
...
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Total, Free: LongInt;
begin
  Total:=DiskSize(Disk) div 1024;
  Free:=DiskFree(Disk) div 1024;
  Gauge1.MaxValue:=Total;
  Gauge1.Progress:=Free;
  Label1.Caption:='Total size - '+IntToStr(Total);
  Label2.Caption:='Free - '+IntToStr(Free);
end;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Disk:=ComboBox1.ItemIndex+1;
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

Here you have another option using the [`Win32_LogicalDisk`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;

procedure  GetWin32_LogicalDiskSize(const drive: string);
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk Where Caption=%s',[QuotedStr(drive)]),'WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  if oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 then
  begin
    Writeln(Format('FreeSpace  %s Bytes',[FormatFloat('#,',FWbemObject.FreeSpace)]));// Uint64
    Writeln(Format('Size       %s Bytes',[FormatFloat('#,',FWbemObject.Size)]));// Uint64
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      GetWin32_LogicalDiskSize('C:');
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Seems a lot more complex, although I know you are heavily into WMI. Are there any advantages over the plain Win32 based approach?

Comment: @David The main advantage is which you can obtain the info from a remote computer as well. also using  the same WMI class you can obtain more information about the disk with a single call.

Comment: those comments would be beneficial to include in the answer, otherwise it looks like a laborious way to achieve the same thing

Comment: @David, I Agree with you, now my comments explain the advantages about use the WMI approach. Also the purpose of my answer was show another way to accomplish the same task, always is good handle another alternatives to accomplish a task.

Answer (score 1):

Some may find this useful - it will give you total and free disk space by Volume's DeviceID. It also uses WMI like RRUZ's answer, but it works with DeviceID, so it has the same advantages + it also works with unmaped devices and drivers (or mapped to path).

```
procedure DiskSizesFromVolumeDeviceID(deviceID:string);
var
  WMIServices : ISWbemServices;
  Root        : ISWbemObjectSet;
  Item: Variant;
  i: Integer;
  Cap:TCap;
begin
  try
  WMIServices := CoSWbemLocator.Create.ConnectServer('.', 'root\cimv2','', '', '', '', 0,     nil);
  Root  := WMIServices.ExecQuery(Format('SELECT Capacity, FreeSpace FROM Win32_Volume     WHERE DeviceID="%s"', [StringReplace(deviceID, '\', '\\', [rfReplaceAll])]),'WQL', 0, nil);
  for i := 0 to Root.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Item := Root.ItemIndex(i);

    TotalSpace := ( Item.Capacity);
    FreeSpace := (Item.FreeSpace);
  End;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way use this code:

```pascal
var
    lpFreeBytesAvailableToCaller, 
    lpTotalNumberOfBytes, 
    lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes : TLargeInteger; // Int64;
begin
   ...
   GetDiskFreeSpaceExA(PChar(path_to_dir), lpFreeBytesAvailableToCaller, lpTotalNumberOfBytes, @lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes);
   ...
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd chime in in share the solution I ended up implementing based on what I've gathered in the accepted answer:

```
function GetDriveCapacity(const Drive: Integer): Int64;
begin
  Result:= DiskSize(Drive);
end;

function GetDriveSpaceFree(const Drive: Integer): Int64;
begin
  Result:= DiskFree(Drive);
end;

function GetDriveSpaceUsed(const Drive: Integer): Int64;
begin
  Result:= GetDriveCapacity(Drive) - GetDriveSpaceFree(Drive);
end;

function GetDriveSpaceUsedPct(const Drive: Integer): Single;
var
  U, C: Int64;
begin
  try
    U:= GetDriveSpaceUsed(Drive);
    C:= GetDriveCapacity(Drive);
    Result:= (U / C) * 100;
  except
    Result:= -1;
  end;
end;
```

The core of everything here starts with `GetDriveSpaceUsedPct`. This returns a float between 0 and 100 representing the percentage of space available on a disk.

NOTE: Refer to the documentation for `DiskSize` and `DiskFree` when it comes to using the `Drive` parameter.

Usage:

```
procedure TForm1.TmrTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  Perc: Double;
begin
  //C Drive Usage
  Perc:= GetDriveSpaceUsedPct(3);
  ...
  //D Drive Usage
  Perc:= GetDriveSpaceUsedPct(4);
  ...
end;
```